# JS: Comparing content in table-cells with cookie data and changing CSS class when success

Tags: javascript, cookies, html-table, toggleclass

I have a pre-rendered static website, in which I want to highlight a name in a table-cell. The name is written into a cookie on the system of the user **OR** in a session on the server. This name has to be compared with all names in the table-cells listed. The table-cell with the matching name has then to be switched to the given class for highlighting. I guess this has to be made with JS. I don't know much JS unfortunately.

If it helps, I can print out some JS code into every single table-cell when pre-rendering the website. Maybe this is useful when changing the CSS class?

---

### Example:

The cookie says that it is "Claus".

---

### Original Table:

```
<table>
 <tr><td class="tdback">Arnie</td></tr>
 <tr><td class="tdback">Mary</td></tr>
 <tr><td class="tdback">Claus</td></tr>
 <tr><td class="tdback">Donald</td></tr>
</table>
```

---

### Final Table:

```
<table>
 <tr><td class="tdback">Arnie</td></tr>
 <tr><td class="tdback">Mary</td></tr>
 <tr><td class="tdactive">Claus</td></tr>
 <tr><td class="tdback">Donald</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If the answer works for you, please mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use javascript to get cookies you can reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

Well hopefully the table has an `id`, if not you can still get the element another way, but for this example i'll get it using an `id`:

```
var cookie = "yourInnerHtml";
var list = document.getElementById("yourTable").getElementsByTagName("td");

for (var n = 0; n < list.length; n++) {
    if (list[n].innerHTML == cookie) {
        list[n].className = "tdactive";
    }
}
```

This should work with the given example. It first gets all the `"td"` element's in the table, then for each of them checks if the `.innerHTML` is the same as your `cookie`. If it is, it changes that elements class.

**UPDATE:**

I removed the unnecessary return statements and now it should work, as well as highlight all occurrences.

Comment: I got the right cookie value now, but how and where do I include and execute this code?

Comment: @PhilG You can add this to your javascript file right after getting the cookie and change the following: set the variable "cookie" to the `td` elements name, change where it says `"yourTable"` to actually be the table's `id`. That's it.

Comment: hey tom, sorry but this doesn't work - i've set up a fiddle, maybe you can help me: https://jsfiddle.net/gc13aLw4/

Comment: @PhilG I found the issue, return false should be after the `for` loop, not inside of it. The answer is now correctly updated, sorry for the inconvenience. Your implementation is flawless.